# Full post on listing page [Gatsby starter blog]

Tags: gatsby

I'm using [gatsby's blog starter template](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-blog) but want to have full posts in the listing page -- not just an excerpt. On the listing page file (blog.js) I see this is what is pulling the excerpt.

```
  <p
    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
       __html: node.frontmatter.description || node.excerpt,
                      }}
  />
```

Is there a simple way to pull the full post? I see on the full blog post file (blog-post.js) it's pulling from here:

```
<MDXRenderer>{post.body}</MDXRenderer>
```

The MDXRederes is from the gatsby mdx plugin, which I also added to the listing file but it's not working. Any directions on what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your loop is correct and the data fetching too, if you want to display the full post you need to set it when you use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` with something like this:

```
 <article dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: node.html}}/>
```

Keep in mind that for `.md` or `.mdx` it is inherited to get the `html` property (which in fact is what prints). So you just need to replace the property that is printing, replacing the excerpt or description for the HTML itself.

In the docs you've provided, they print the full post from:         `<section dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: post.html }} />` where `post` comes from `const post = data.markdownRemark`.